# Issues unit testing data dependent REST apis

Tags: c#, unit-testing, web-applications, xunit, xunit.net

I have been tasked to write unit tests for an authentication service, coded and maintained by my coworker.
I have been given a set of REST apis which allow me to use such service to authenticate a user and get a JWT token, to change a user's password and all the common things an authentication service does. I chose the xunit framework to write my test modules.
Now, each unit test should be completely isolated from the others and all tests should be able to pass regardless of the order of execution. I'm finding it very difficult to adhere to these practices though:

1) some of the REST apis I'm testing modify the DB and this may cause annoying side effects. E.G.: if i test the api to change a user's password and somehow I can't revert the change, I'm not able to have such test pass anymore unless I manually access the db to revert it.

2) I can't run all my tests in parallel and some of them are not so fast. Also, side effects again  E.G.: if I test that a user is blocked as a result of many wrong login attempts, I must make sure that I don't use the same user to test a normal login and that is becoming increasingly annoying as the amount of tests grows. Also, I have to wait until the lock period expires to check that the user is able to login again.

Many tests seem too coupled to each other and all seem to be too much dependent on the state of the DB. I don't even have access to the DB so I'm forced to ask the service's developer to modify the test DB in order to satisfy my needs.
The entire process feels so clunky. What are the best practices to structure unit test when I can't mock up the data layer and what I'm testing is highly dependent on data?

I have come to the conclusion that the right approach should have been the following: my coworker should have been writing unit tests directly against his backend modules, without passing through web api calls. That way he could have easily mocked up the data layer, effectively decoupling unit tests from the db. Only then, maybe I could have written some integration tests to test REST apis. Is my conclusion unreasonable?

Comment: unit test are tests without any real dependency (any depedency has to be faked/mocked). Once you use any real dependency you are on integration test.

Comment: _any depedency has to be faked/mocked_ or mock only dependencies which are slow or very very very complicated. Anything which uses web servers, file system, databases or other external resources should be mocked. EF Core or Sqlite provide "In-Memory" feature, which give possibility not to mock databases fully.